# UITabBarController offsetting content at first sight

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller

I'm having trouble with my `UITabBarController` in the sense that my first view of the first `UIViewController` is being offset about 20 pixels to the bottom. Whenever I tab around and/or return to the first view controller (same instance, not released), it's fine. It's only the first encounter.

**My steps:**

1. I am allocating and initializing a `UITabBarController`
2. I am allocating and initializing 3 instances of `UIViewController`
3. I am setting the `viewControllers` property to an array of the above mentioned 3 items

**My code:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Allocate and initialize view controllers
    self.debtsViewController = [[DebtsViewController alloc] init];
    self.debtsViewController.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Debts", nil);
    self.debtsViewController.tabBarController = self;
    self.conclusionsViewController = [[ConclusionsViewController alloc] init];
    self.conclusionsViewController.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Entries", nil);
    self.conclusionsViewController.tabBarController = self;
    self.settingsViewController = [[SettingsViewController alloc] init];
    self.settingsViewController.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Settings", nil);
    // Assign to tabBarController
    self.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.debtsViewController, self.conclusionsViewController, self.settingsViewController, nil];
}
```

Any ideas?

Screenshot: http://cl.ly/image/2E0S001d0Q2x (notice the black space just above the `UITableViewController`)

Comment: are you using xibs? Is debts a `UITableViewController` or `UIViewController`?

Comment: `DebtsViewController` is a `UITableViewController` with a .xib-file defining a grouped view style.

Comment: I recreated your issue. It seems that you are putting `UITabBarViewController` inside the `UINavigationController`. Unless intented-this is wrong and usually it works the other way(you put `UINavigationController` inside the `UITabBarViewController`. Are you sure this VCs hierarchy is correct?

Comment: This is actually intended (however I am new to obj-C, so I have no idea if this is the best/correct solution. I am showing a button in my nav bar that I want to be accessible from any of the three VC's, so I figured this hierarchy.

Comment: Thinking about it that is also possible the other way around. I'll try it out.

Answer (score 1):

i solved this problem.

```

```
[tab setSelectedIndex:1];
[tab setSelectedIndex:0];
```

```

you can manually reset the offset by switch the tab bar after the tabbarcontroller initialized

Answer (score 0):

Having a glance at your screenshot made me think, that actually you should have 3 `UINavigationControllers` inside the `UITabBarViewController`. Their navigationBars will be(almost) lookalike, but it will be 3 separate instances. What does 'Settings' have in common with 'Debts'? Why would they share same navigation?

The point of using `UITabBarViewController` is to have independent sections of the app. I strongly recommend you [Apple's guide.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011313)